# How to stop android REDELIVER_INTENT background service?

Tags: android, service

I use background service in my audio player project. I create my service as "REDELIVER_INTENT" so if the service stop it starts again and continues to play music. But after i destroy it with "stopForeground(true);" service is stopping but it starts working again after a while. Is there any way to stop "REDELIVER_INTENT" background service and prevent starting again itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `stopService()` (on a `Context`) or `stopSelf()` (on the `Service` itself) to stop the service. `stopForeground()` only removes the foreground aspect of the service; it does not stop the service.

Comment: I have tried "android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());" before but it but it has not been beneficial. stopSelf() looks like it worked I will continue to test. What is the difference between android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()) and stopself() ? Why the first one doesnt work ?

Comment: @Shockelduck: `killProcess()` kills a process. It does not stop a service. In particular, it does not tell Android to stop recreating the process and service.